# Dependabot hanging on a certain gem, can I totally ignore it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rubygems, dependabot

So I am running Dependabot on our ruby on rails repository, and there is two specific gems that apparently just don't work with Dependabot (ffi-yajl is one, here is a issue raised by dependabot saying it doesn't work https://github.com/chef/ffi-yajl/issues/108).

I have tried adding ignore rules to the dependabot.yml files, but from reading around online the ignore rules filter out the selected gems AFTER it grabs all the updates, so the jobs still get stuck on these two gems whether I ignore them or not.  Checking the logs its still spamming the logs with attempts to update these two after I added ignore rules, including ignore rules for the group the ffi-yajl is apart of (chef).

```
  ignore:
     - dependency-name: "chef"
     - dependency-name: "ffi-yajl"
```

That is in my dependabot.yml file under "updates" and I am still seeing these lines in the log of it trying to update these gems.  I want to find a way to totally ignore the gems and not even try to LOOK for updates so that way the jobs will stop hanging when it gets to them and the logs stop being spammed with attempts.

Comment: Is this a bug in your repo? The link leads to an issue from `dependabot-preview` which is an old version. Maybe this was fixed in the meantime?